# Prevent localstorage from saving if input is required but not filled?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code im making, and im wondering if i could prevent the localstorage from saving unless the required inputs in my form is filled out correctly. Right now the localstorage works with my submit button, but still saves if it gives me the "Please fill this field" message. Any help would be appriciated ! Here is the function i use to save the data.

```
let writeDate = () => {
if (isLocalStorageEnabled) {
    $("confirmBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
        let getItem = localStorage.getItem('bookingDate');
        let bookingDate = getItem ? JSON.parse(getItem) : [];

        let bk = Object.assign({}, bookingInfo);
        bk.name = $("fname").value;
        bk.amount = $("famount").value;
        bk.date = $("fdate").value;
        bk.time = $("ftime").value;
        bookingDate.push(bk);

        let date = JSON.stringify(bookingDate);
        localStorage.setItem("bookingDate", date);
    });
};};
```

Comment: Use the [submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) event on the form instead of a `click` event on the confirm btn.

Comment: the first thing inside the listener should be a check for filled fields, if all needed fields have some value, then proceed to your current code

Comment: add `type=submit` to `confirmBtn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toby, you can implement it as following.

I tried to keep variable name as same as your question.

html

```
<div>
  <form onsubmit="return onSubmit(event)">
    <label for="fname">Name:
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" required />
    </label>

    <label for="famount">Amount:
      <input type="number" id="famount" name="famount" required />
    </label>

    <label for="fdate">Date:
      <input type="date" id="fdate" name="fdate" required />
    </label>

    <label for="ftime">Time:
      <input type="time" id="ftime" name="ftime" required />
    </label>
    
    <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

javascript

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  const prevBookingDate = localStorage.getItem('bookingDate');
  let bookingDate = prevBookingDate ? JSON.parse(prevBookingDate) : [];

  const { fname, famount, fdate, ftime } = e.target
  const bk = {
    name: fname.value,
    amount: famount.value,
    date: fdate.value,
    time: ftime.value
  };
  bookingDate.push(bk);

  let date = JSON.stringify(bookingDate);
  localStorage.setItem("bookingDate", date);
}
```